# Is this kind of a statement possible?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following:

```
var contents = new[]
    {
        "Theme Gallery", "Converted Forms", "Page Output Cache", "Master Page",
        "(no title)", ".css", ".xml", ".wsp", ".jpg", ".png", ".master"
        , ".000" , "Page Output Cache" , "_catalogs", "Style Library", "Cache Profiles"
    };

string fileUrl = siteCollectionEntity.Url + '/' + item.Url;
```

And I'd like to write a statement that will prevent a loop from continuing if a URL contains any of the words found in contents. Apologies for the following poor syntax, but I think it will help to explain better what I'm trying to do... Basically something like the following:

```
if (fileUrl.Contains(contents)) continue;
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: So if my file is called "Definitely NOT the Theme Gallery", I can't use it? Assuming this is for SharePoint, there must be better ways of checking for system files and folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var contains = contents.Any(i => fileUrl.Contains(i));
```

Explanation:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx - there is a `.Any()` method that `LINQ` provides you.
2. It works as the following: it accepts a function reference (lambda in this case) which accepts one argument of the same type as your collection item (`string` in your case, I called it `i`) and must return a boolean. If there is `true` returned for some element - the whole `.Any()` returns true.

So basically it passes every item of the `contents` array as `i` into the `fileUrl.Contains(i)` expression until one returns `true`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand this one... could you explain a bit further?

Comment: @ElvisLikeBear: google on LINQ. Will make your programming life much more productive.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be.aspx)

> Determines whether the specified array contains elements that match
>   the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

Something like

```
if(Array.Exists(contents, s => fileUrl.Contains(s))) continue;
```

Comment: @zerkms, corrected, sorry. Was looking at the List<string> usage.

Answer (score 0):

File URL is case insensitive. So I think you should do:

```
if (contents.Any(c => fileUrl.IndexOf(c, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1))
{
    continue;
}
```